# handling javascript object existence checks globally

Tags: javascript

My JS developers always miss checking the object existence causing doucument.getElementByID is null problem. is there a way to handle this globally than adding the check for every single object. or is it possible to handle/suppress it during runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Beat your developers with a "Javascript for Dummies" book and then make them go back and fix their code.

Seriously.

Error suppression can seem like a good thing at first, but it'll haunt you later down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Suppress all errors:

```
window.onerror = function(){return true;};
```

But you <strike>may want to</strike> ***really should*** handle errors in a [more decent](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/) fashion.

Comment: That's why I added a nice link ;)